# Why can't I add a row in HTML with jQuery in this code?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I did the actual process of adding row in HTML by jQuery but it does not seem to work. Could you provide a solution? How can I solve this problem? The "add row" button is not working, why? I tried it in many ways but failed. Can anyone help me?
I also tried it with JavaScript but got the same result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addRow").click(function() {
    $('table').append("<tr>" +

      "<td align="
      center "><input type="
      text " name="
      id_country " value="
      <?php echo $row["id_country"];?>
      "><br>" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td><input type="
      text " name="
      name " value="
      <?php echo $row["name"];?>
      "><br>" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td><input type="
      text " name="
      codes " value="
      <?php echo $row["codes"];?>
      "><br>" +
      "</td>" +

      "<td><input type="
      text " name="
      types " value="
      <?php echo $row["types"];?>
      "><br>" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td><input type="
      text " name="
      t_code " value="
      <?php echo $row["t_code"];?>
      "><br>" +
      "</td>
      "<td><input type="
      text " name="
      range_name " value="
      <?php echo $row["range_name"];?>
      "><br>" +
      "</td>
      "<td align="
      center "><input name="
      usubmit " type="
      submit " value="
      Update " /></td>" +
      "<td align="
      center "><input name="
      dsubmit " type="
      submit " value="
      Delete " /></td>" +

      "</tr>"
    );

  });
}); <
/script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>View Records</title>
</head>



<body>
  <div class="form">
    <p><a href="input_auth/index.php">Home</a> | <a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a> | <a href="input_auth/in_out.php">Logout</a></p>
    <h2>View Records</h2>
  </div>
  <table width="100%" border="1" id="table" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><strong>Id_country</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>codes</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Medium</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Medium_code</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Class</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <form name="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
        <tr>

          <td align="center"><input type="text" name="id_country" value="<?php echo $row[" id_country "];?>"><br>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row[" name "];?>"><br>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="codes" value="<?php echo $row[" codes "];?>"><br>
          </td>

          <td><input type="text" name="types" value="<?php echo $row[" types "];?>"><br>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="t_code" value="<?php echo $row[" t_code "];?>"><br>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="range_name" value="<?php echo $row[" range_name "];?>"><br>
          </td>
          <td align="center"><input name="usubmit" type="submit" value="Update" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input name="dsubmit" type="submit" value="Delete" /></td>

        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"> <input type="button" name="asubmit" class="addRow" value="Add Row"></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </tbody>

  </table>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Invalid Javascript syntax, you need to escape your double quotes `"value=\"<?php echo $variable ?>\""+`. Otherwise you are ending the string context.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got it and solved it.

Comment: How can I delete my post now? Does anyone help?

Comment: Please post another question explaining the issue you are having along with the applicable code that is producing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you enclose a string with `"` but that string has several instances of `"` within it (e.g. `"<td align="center">..."`). So when the javascript parser evaluates that line, it will decide the string ends at the second `"`, after `=`. So to the parser, the string is `"<td align="` and there's an invalid token center before the start of the next string). So the whole expression is messed up for javascript.

The solution is to replace all in-string instances of `"` with `'` like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addRow").click(function() {
        $('table').append("<tr>" +
            "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='id_country' value='<?php echo $row['id_country'];?>'><br>" +"</td>" +
            "<td><input type='text ' name='name ' value=<?php echo $row['name'];?>'><br>" +"</td>" +
            "<td><input type='text ' name='codes ' value='<?php echo $row['codes'];?>'><br>" +"</td>" +
            "<td><input type='text ' name='types ' value='<?php echo $row['types'];?>'><br>" +"</td>" +
            "<td><input type='text ' name='t_code ' value='<?php echo $row['t_code';?>'><br>" +"</td>" +
            "<td><input type='text ' name='range_name ' value='<?php echo $row['range_name'];?>'><br>" +"</td>" +
            "<td align='center '><input name='usubmit ' type='submit ' value='Update ' /></td>" +
            "<td align='center '><input name='dsubmit ' type='submit ' value='Delete ' /></td>" +
            "</tr>"
        );
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="table" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><strong>Id_country</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>codes</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Medium</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Medium_code</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Class</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Edit</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Delete</strong></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1"/>
        <tr>

            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="id_country" value="<?php echo $row[" id_country "];?>"><br>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row[" name "];?>"><br>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="codes" value="<?php echo $row[" codes "];?>"><br>
            </td>

            <td><input type="text" name="types" value="<?php echo $row[" types "];?>"><br>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="t_code" value="<?php echo $row[" t_code "];?>"><br>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="range_name" value="<?php echo $row[" range_name "];?>"><br>
            </td>
            <td align="center"><input name="usubmit" type="submit" value="Update"/></td>
            <td align="center"><input name="dsubmit" type="submit" value="Delete"/></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="button" name="asubmit" class="addRow" value="Add Row"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Alternatively, you can also:

- use `\"` as in-string quotes. The `\` treats the following character as a literal, i.e. does not mean opening or closing quote for a string.
- use `'` as external quotes for the string, and use `"` as-is for in-string quotes. `\"` also works but isn't necessary. But you can't use the same `'` for in-string quotes as the compiler will interpret it as end-of-string.

Comment: How can I delete my post now? Does anyone help?